# How do I add a bottom texture to pumpkins?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm currently working on my own texture pack, and I want to add a pumpkin_bottom texture. I figured out that I should add it to the block model, but since pumpkins are defined as cube_column blocks, I tried changing them to cube_bottom_top blocks. However, this resulted in the textures breaking and being replaced with the purple-black-chequered texture.

**How do I add a bottom texture to Minecraft pumpkins? Do I need to define them as another type of block from default? Is this a conflict related to Jack o' Lantern blocks?**

The texture names (all .png) are:

- pumpkin_bottom
- pumpkin_side
- pumpkin_top

The code within the original block model file (pumpkin.json) is:

```
{
  "parent": "block/cube_column",
  "display": {
    "firstperson_righthand": {
      "rotation": [ 0, 135, 0 ],
      "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "scale": [ 0.40, 0.40, 0.40 ]
    }
  },
  "textures": {
    "end": "block/pumpkin_top",
    "side": "block/pumpkin_side"
  }
}
```

These are my changes to the pumpkin.json file:

```
{
  "parent": "block/cube_bottom_top",
  "display": {
    "firstperson_righthand": {
      "rotation": [ 0, 135, 0 ],
      "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "scale": [ 0.40, 0.40, 0.40 ]
    }
  },
  "textures": {
    "side": "block/pumpkin_side"
    "bottom": "block/pumpkin_bottom",
    "top": "block/pumpkin_top"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should insert the file names of models and textures and the contents of the model files. Otherwise there can be infinitely many reasons why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem, in your `pumpkin.json` you've missed a comma after `"side": "block/pumpkin_side"`, this also explains the broken texture. So the working json file looks like this:

```
{
  "parent": "block/cube_bottom_top",
  "display": {
    "firstperson_righthand": {
      "rotation": [ 0, 135, 0 ],
      "translation": [ 0, 0, 0 ],
      "scale": [ 0.40, 0.40, 0.40 ]
    }
  },
  "textures": {
    "side": "block/pumpkin_side",
    "bottom": "block/pumpkin_bottom",
    "top": "block/pumpkin_top"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah of course, that did it! Thanks :-)